# How can I get source property which is binded in Silverlight 4?

Tags: reflection, silverlight-4.0

Here is an example:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
  <Control Value="{Binding Parent.Margins.Top, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"/>
</Grid>
```

I want to get type of the "Top" property to set correct value (null if it's nullable or "empty" parameter). How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Well, i thought I already did. I'm trying to use GetType() on Top property, but in order to do this, I need that Top property.

Answer (score 0):

If you write an IValueConverter, and use that as the Converter for the Binding expression, then inside of the Convert/ConvertBack methods, you should get the value (typed as "object") and you can use GetType() on that to inspect it and decide how you want to act.

Comment: Can you explain what about an IValueConverter is not sufficient?